# When using callbacks inside a loop in javascript, is there any way to save a variable that's updated in the loop for use in the callback?

Tags: javascript, callback

Let's say I have something as follows:

```
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
  var variable = variables[i];
  otherVariable.doSomething(variable, function(err){ //callback for when doSomething ends
    do something else with variable;
  }
```

By the time the callbacks are called, `variable` will inevitably be the last variable for all the callbacks, instead of being a different one for each callback, as I would like. I realize that I could pass `variable` to `doSomething()` and then get that passed back as part of the callback, but `doSomething()` is part of an external library, and I'd rather not mess around with the source code for that.

Do those of you that know JavaScript better than I do know if there are any alternative ways to do what I'd like to do?

Best, and thanks,
Sami

Comment: Don't know much about JS, but it seems that you can now use `let`:
`let i = 0; i < length; ++i`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A common, if ugly, way of dealing with this situation is to use another function that is immediately invoked to create a scope to hold the variable.

```
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  var variable = variables[i];
  otherVariable.doSomething(function(v) { return function(err) { /* something with v */ }; }(variable));
}
```

Notice that inside the immediately invoked function the callback that is being created, and returned, references the parameter to the function `v` and not the outside `variable`.  To make this read much better I would suggest extracting the constructor of the callback as a named function.

```
function callbackFor(v) {
  return function(err) { /* something with v */ };
}
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  var variable = variables[i];
  otherVariable.doSomething(callbackFor(variable));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help in my case because doSomething() is a function from a library that I don't want to edit. As this library gets updated, I'll have to keep reediting the source code and that's something that I just don't want to deal with. Assuming I cannot alter the function doSomething(), is there anything I can do?

Comment: This doesn't require any change to `doSomething()`. I assumed that `doSomething` simply took a callback and that the inclusion of the `variable` parameter was something that you might be proposing to change. If the signature of `doSomething` is `doSomething(val, callback)` then just modify my example to `otherVariable.doSomething(variable, callbackFor(variable))`. The important thing is that a new scope is created, by calling a function, to hold onto the value of `variable` for the callback function.

Comment: Hmm so I guess I'm a little confused. The way `doSomething()` works is that it's passed the variable, and then eventually `doSomething()` will call the callback function specified, where the first parameter is any potential error code that resulted from `doSomething()`. If I put a `function(variable)` wrapper around the callback to create a new scope, wouldn't that `function(variable)` become the callback instead, and the parameter `variable` actually be the error message?

Answer (score 42):

Ok I've seemed to figure this out. What I needed to do was to put a `function(var)` wrapper around `otherVariable.doSomething()`, so the updated code looks as follows:

```
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
  var variable = variables[i];
  (function(var){ //start wrapper code
    otherVariable.doSomething(var, function(err){ //callback for when doSomething ends
      do something else with var; //please note that i'm dealing with var here, not variable
    }
  })(variable);//passing in variable to var here
}
```

hope this helps anybody else that gets stuck on something like this in the future!

@aparker42, i'd still love to hear your answer to my question in the comment to your question, since that still does confuse me.

EDIT: of course, since this is javascript, you wouldn't want to use `var` as a variable name.

Comment: Yes, this is essentially the same thing as what my answer had. The difference is that you use the immediately invoked function to create a scope in which you do the call to `doSomething`. My answer just created the callback in that scope and then returned it. In the end they both achieve the same thing.

Comment: To support and clarify, yes, this is the same answer that aparker42 put, just in a different format. The callback in that case is not being CALLED by doSomething, it's immediately returning a value.

Comment: Maybe not such a good idea to have an identifier named `var` in JavaScript.

Comment: Great work around, saved my code.