# NodeJS callback out of sync

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm pretty new to NodeJS and I am trying to solve the following problem related to callback functions.

```
var lib = require('someLibrary');

function main() {
  for(var i = 0; i <10; i++) {
    var num = someArray[i];
    lib.validate(function(result) {
      if(result.value === num) {
         console.log('Found it');
      }
    }
  }
}
main();
```

Now here since ***validate()*** takes a callback, my ***num*** is always out of sync. Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: `var num =` -> `let num =`

Comment: @JamesThorpe it's the same problem in the end, just with 1 added step.

Comment: @KevinB Yeah - but I feel there's probably a better target for it than that Q

Comment: [This one perhaps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053965/when-using-callbacks-inside-a-loop-in-javascript-is-there-any-way-to-save-a-var) as it deals with the local variable, though it itself has been closed as a dupe of my first choice...

Comment: @KevinB That worked. Thanks. How was this solved for ECMAScript versions <6 ?

Comment: @OmkarSambhus self executing functions, or using a functional iteration method such as [].forEach. An example of the former can be found at the canonical post James linked.

Comment: @KevinB Found it. Thanks :)