# JavaScript Variable Stuck inside Loop - Can't Access

Tags: javascript, html, closures

I'm doing an AJAX call to retrieve all stores in a certain state. The problem is, is that the last 2 lines can't access any of the variable content that I built up in the return function from the `get` call.

```
    var states = ['TX', 'AZ];

    for(j = 0; j < states.length; j++) {
        var fullHTML = '';
        var full2;
        $.get("//127.0.0.1:8000/api/state-stores/", {state: states[j]}, function(data) {
            console.log(data.stores.length);

            for(var i = 0; i < data.stores.length; i++) {
                store_html = '<tr><td>' + data.stores[i].name + '</td><td>'
                fullHTML += store_html;
            }
        })
        // PROBLEM HERE
        console.log(fullHTML); //empty
        $("#" + states[j].toLowerCase() + "-table").html(fullHTML); //does nothing
    }
```

What can I do to fix this? I've been trying weird global variable tricks and all sorts of hack-y things but nothing's working.

**UPDATE**
I also tried placing my last two lines **inside** the `$.get` call but `states[j]` is for some reason inaccessible inside the loop.
After debugging, it seems like just `j` from the outer loop is inaccessible inside this return function. Is there a way to fix that?

---

**UPDATE 2**

I followed the advice given in the answer and I **am** getting properly concatenated strings for `fullHTML`, **but**, each `fullHTML` string is replacing only the **last** state in the table. It's as if the `TX` tag is the only one receiving all the updates. I think this is closure-based but I don't know how to resolve this.

```
$(function() {
    var states = ['AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'GA', 'NV', 'NC', 'SC', 'TX'];
    // var states = ['CA'];
    for(var j = 0; j < states.length; j++) {
        var current = j;
        $.get("//127.0.0.1:8000/api/state-stores/", {state: states[j]}, function(data) {
            var fullHTML = '';
            for(var i = 0; i < data.stores.length; i++) {
                store_html = '<tr><td>' + data.stores[i].name + '</td><td>' + data.stores[i].address + '<span class="small-table"><br>' + data.stores[i].city + '</span></td><td>' + data.stores[i].city + '</td><td>' + data.stores[i].state + '</td><td>' + data.stores[i].postal_code + '</td></tr>'
                fullHTML += store_html;
            }
            $('#' + states[current].toLowerCase() + '-table').html(fullHTML);
        })  
    }

});
```

Comment: It's not _stuck_ in loop, it about timing. You're accessing the variable before the data is loaded from the server and assigned to variable. **That's ok, but how to solve this?** Just move the last statement inside the `$.get()` callback.

Comment: @Tushar please see my update to my question as to why I wanted to do it this way but ran into a problem.

Comment: @qarthandso See my edit for a working solution to your `Update 2`. Also, I'm not sure why this was marked as duplicate (to that question in particular, as that's not what you were asking, but this [was asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053965/when-using-callbacks-inside-a-loop-in-javascript-is-there-any-way-to-save-a-var) somewhere else, but the duplicate isn't pointing to a relevant question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an **asynchronous** $.get function. That is to say, code execution will **not** wait at that line until the $.get is done, perform the callback function, and then continue onto the next line after the $.get. In reality, it will perform an asynchronous call to the $.get function, and continue execution immediately to the `console.log(fullHTML)` line. There is no guarantee at this point that the $.get function has finished or even started, as it's being executed asynchronously.

<s>As for your issue with the accessibility to `j`, that's a problem that comes back to closures. Your `j` variable, when accessed inside of the $.get callback, will reference the `j` variable that has been looped through already, and will return the incorrect `j` value, as you probably want the value of `j` from when the $.get request was executed. So, you'll want to store `j` inside of the local closure by declaring it explicitly like `var current = j`, the instead of referencing `j` inside of your $.get callback, you'd reference `current`, and it would perform as intended.</s> **This doesn't work!**

**EDIT**

We can force create a new scope if we declare an anonymous function and execute the $.get inside of that context. It's not a pretty solution, but it works!

To fix your code, put your calls inside of the $.get callback like so:

```
var states = ['TX', 'AZ'];

for(j = 0; j < states.length; j++) {
    var fullHTML = '';
    var full2;
    (function() {
        var current = j;
        $.get("//127.0.0.1:8000/api/state-stores/", {state: states[j]}, function(data) {
            console.log(data.stores.length);

            for(var i = 0; i < data.stores.length; i++) {
                store_html = '<tr><td>' + data.stores[i].name + '</td><td>'
                fullHTML += store_html;
            }
            console.log(fullHTML); // not empty anymore
            $("#" + states[current].toLowerCase() + "-table").html(fullHTML); //does stuff
        });
   })();
}
```

Now, your code will only perform the lines that were broken before AFTER it has populated the `fullHTML` variable.

Comment: I wanted to do it this way but also ran into a problem. Please see my updated question for why this method didn't work for me.

Comment: @qarthandso Updated my answer to address that.

Comment: This is the exact solution. Thank you so much. Why is this IIFE necessary? to store the current `state` value?

Comment: I'm no JS expert, so I may be spewing nonsense, but I believe it's because we have to force declare a new closure that can't have it's contents touched by the context the `for` loop is running in (either `window` or possibly whatever context is denoted by `$`). Declaring an IIFE gives us just that.