# How to set a cookie with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

I want to create a cookie which will remember a product that costumer wants to add to wish list.
Every product and button which is named heart in code has its specific array value which is f.
For some reason this code doesnt create a cookie:

```
var hearts=document.getElementsByClassName("heart");
var f;
for(f=0;f<heart.length;f++) {

hearts[f].addEventListener("click",function(){setCookie(f);});  

  }

  function setCookie(f){
    var d=new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + 365*24*60*60*1000);     
    var expires="expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie="product="+f+";"+domain=localhost+expires+";path=/"; 


  }
```

Comment: Look at your JS console. Note the syntax error.

Comment: No error in console.

Comment: `document.cookie = "product=" + f + ";" + domain = localhost + expires + ";path=/";` is not valid JS. If there isn't a syntax error then something else is wrong as well.

Comment: yeah i edited as well,this works:    document.cookie="product="+f+";"+expires+";path=/";

Comment: However i have another problem the function that sends argument f always sends number 8 which is last in the row of elements.

Comment: See my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed an error by myself.It is realy dumb,sorry for bothering you guys in for loop it should be hearths.length instead of hearth.length.

Comment: Note that it still won't do what you think it does because of how JS closures work.

Comment: Well i still dont get it.I dont get why javascript add listener function doesnt pass actual f counter,but only passes when it finish loop last f.

Comment: Because by the time the callback runs `f` has already been incremented through its iteration. Closures capture the variable *itself*, not its value. See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/438992, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46245591/438992, etc.